# Getting workerId by assignmentId

Tags: mechanicalturk

In Amazon Mechanical Turk, when creating an [External Question](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AWSMechTurk/latest/AWSMturkAPI/ApiReference_ExternalQuestionArticle.html) then it will send you each assignment like this:

```
http://tictactoe.amazon.com/gamesurvey.cgi?gameid=01523
&hitId=123RVWYBAZW00EXAMPLE
&assignmentId=123RVWYBAZW00EXAMPLE456RVWYBAZW00EXAMPLE
```

Surprisingly, it doesn't send me the workerId and I can't find any way to do this. The closest method is [GetAssignmentsForHIT](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AWSMechTurk/latest/AWSMturkAPI/ApiReference_GetAssignmentOperation.html) which only gives me the assignment already submitted but I need to render the assignment based on the worker history.

Answer (score 1):

As msha points out, the sending of a workerID parameter to an ExternalQuestion page seems to be deprecated, or at least taken out of the latest version of the documentation.

However, a fellow researcher who's been using MTurk a lot says: "People seem to be using it in the forums. I would go ahead with it...if it ever actually disappears, I'm sure that the developer community will yell very loudly. :) "

I tried it empirically today (2011-08-19), and indeed a workerID is being sent to the ExternalQuestion page I set up on my own server, after the HIT has been accepted. This was in the sandbox. My ExternalQuestion page contained a Java Web Start button (as described here: http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/deploymentInDepth/createWebStartLaunchButtonFunction.html ); I don't know if that made any difference.

Comment: How did you retrieve the workerID? For the hitID etc., I can grab them from the URL itself (like above), but that isn't possible with the workerID.

Answer (score 1):

A recent addition to the API is the [GetAssignment](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AWSMechTurk/latest/AWSMturkAPI/ApiReference_GetAssignmentOperation.html) call, which takes the assignment ID as an argument and will return the Worker ID inside the [Assignment data structure](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AWSMechTurk/latest/AWSMturkAPI/ApiReference_AssignmentDataStructureArticle.html).

Comment: This is wrong. GetAssignment only works for assignments with status Submitted | Approved | Rejected. When processing the external question the assignment has status none. So GetAssignment will result in a InvalidAssignmentState exception

Answer (score 0):

According to the MTurk docs [here](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AWSMechTurk/latest/AWSMturkAPI/ApiReference_ExternalQuestionArticle.html),

> When a Worker accepts your HIT, you can get the ID of the Worker. If
>   your HIT contains a Java Applet, an IFrame, or embedded binary data,
>   the URL contains a value for the workerId. If your HIT does not
>   contain these types of data, or if a Worker has not accepted the HIT,
>   the workerId element doesn't appear.

Haven't tried to confirm this myself yet.

Comment: I think the link you sent is pointing to the deprecated API. http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AWSMechTurk/latest/AWSMturkAPI/ is the new one which doesn't have the "Accept mode".