# Running External HITs on Mechanical Turk - without IFrames

Tags: mechanicalturk

Is there a way to get the HitID, WorkerID, AssignmentID, etc using an External Question system not using IFrames but just a link to an external site, say a survey link etc?
This is required to POST the data back to MTurk to handle the payments.

MTurk Docs suggest only a way to do that using IFrames-http://amzn.to/1q5ZBHV

Something similar to [Running MTurk HITs on external website](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10769152/running-mturk-hits-on-external-website) but i don't want to run it inside an IFrame.

Comment: Answered - https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=155868