# Data collection web-page on AWS using RDS

Tags: javascript, php, node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

I created a static webpage for data collection and used formspree for collecting the forms. It worked cool.

Now, I am willing to extend the project in that I am going to `TurkPrime`. 
It seems I have to deal with the complexities of the web development.

I have set up `AWS` Free Tier. And most probably my research indicates that `RDS` is the way ahead.

Specifically, complexities arise with respect to `how to's`. I am taking the things head on, and planning to first follow [this](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/opsworks/latest/userguide/gettingstarted-node.html) tutorial and then [this](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/create-deploy-nodejs.rds.html). But overall, I would have to design my UI. There, as indicated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10769152/running-mturk-hits-on-external-website), the flow is most likely going to require a key generation as validation.

My questions are:

1. Is this right way to go ahead? How to evaluate right? Minimal code typing, extensively using available frameworks, integration with `AWS` and that too `RDS`.
2. I just need to get a form submitted into the database, don't really wish to spend 3-4 days working on this. Would really appreciate any available template. Not that I hate web development and not willing to learn, but at the moment I have no time to invest in learning.
3. code of my current static page is in `javascript`, i assume it need not be changed, right? If no, is there a way to use the same UI, because its just a form!

**Edit_1**

I am okay even if I have to use `PHP`, no special love for `node.js`, but it gotta be quick and within the restrictions of free tier of AWS